# Did any members of Katrina and the Waves have pet anteaters?

Tags: rock, pop

This certainly seems like an incredibly unnecessary question, but I need it answered to prove a point to a buddy of mine.
Have any of the members of Katrina and the Waves ever have, legally or otherwise, pet anteaters?

Comment: Seems like this would be hard to disprove, because where on earth would anyone ever find an interview quote that says, "No, none of our members ever owned anteaters illegally"?  It's just not a topic that comes up in polite conversation very often.

Answer (score 1):

1) Legal

Balance of probability, none of them has a legal pet anteater.

a) Keeping an anteater is not like keeping a goldfish. Key point here - it's 
something which would attract attention to you.

b) Anteaters are native to Central and South America, so a resident
of any country where they are not native would need relevant permissions etc 
for keeping of an exotic/non-native animal.

c) Members of Katrina and the Waves are US/UK citizens, 
and variously resident in the UK/USA, so would need some 
kind of permit etc to do this, legally. I don't know if such permits 
are in the public domain, but if so, it would be possible to research the point and find out

d) Most of the available internet news items about pet ant-eaters date from 2013 and relate to Angela Goodwin of Oakridge, Oregon, USA who at the time of the articles, kept two.

e) All former band members of K and the W have had musical careers since "Katrina and the Waves" : as ex-members of the band they would be "news" in some shape or form, if they did something unusual.  I can find no internet news items about this.

2) Illegal

There's no evidence I can find to suggest any of them have an illegal anteater, either. Interesting conspiracy theory, I suppose...

3) So? 
I guess nothing short of a direct question and a public confirmation or denial will do.How to do this ?

Katrina Leskanich and Kimerley Rew both have websites : so they are contactable.

According to this link
http://www.protectionracket.com/artists/item/alex-cooper
"Kimberley Rew, Vince de la Cruz and Al Cooper, are still friends, colleagues and business partners in the business that is Kyboside Ltd, 
the company Katrina and the Waves at the beginning of their career."

"Kyboside Music ltd" has a registered business address in London, so the remaining band members are also contactable.

Go for it.....